# You can only install this software on the disk that is running os x

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install

I have 2 disks in my Mac - a new SSD which is my boot drive, and the original disk which came with the mac, which still has OSX installed on it (I haven't figured out what to use this drive for yet).

I noticed when installing an application I got this message and I was surprised because I was sure OSX let you do this.

Can anyone help me understand? Is it not possible to put applications anywhere except on the boot partition?

Comment: Could you tell us which application you were trying to install? Most applications can be installed anywhere, but perhaps this application integrates with the operating system in a way that requires it to be on the OS X drive.

Comment: It's called Amplitube3, by IK Multimedia. If it's something that can be set on a per-application basis, that at least makes some sense... maybe a security thing? This app also doesn't like Migration Assistant.

Comment: My guess is the authorisation needs to be on the current boot drive. The plugin itself will also need to be inside /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins so your DAW can find it. If you have that symlinked somewhere else it will put it in the correct place.